# Certain USB-C cable / port combination not working

Tags: networking, usb, 20.04, usb-c

I have a USB extension hub with the following specs (ASCII art is worth 10000 words):

```
                  ----------------------- 
                  |                     | 
                  |               [Type A female] -> output 1
   Input -> [Type A female]       [Type A female] -> output 2
                  |               [Type A female] -> output 3
                 LED              [Type A female] -> output 4
                  |                     | 
                  -----------------------
```

I have the following cables cables:

1. `(Type A male) <--> (Type A male)`
2. `(Type C male) <--> (Type A male)`
3. `(Type C male) <--> (Type C male)`

My Ubuntu box has both Type A and Type C female connectors.
I also have an external SSD that has a Type C female connector.

The combination of cable 2, my Ubuntu desktop and the hub does not work. In summary,
the following combinations have been tried:

```
 | Cable # | Cable side one   | Cable side two   | works? | Conclusion          |
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |    1    | Desktop Type A   | USB hub input A  | yes    | USB hub works       |      
 |    2    | Desktop Type C   | USB hub input A  | No     | ???                 |
 |    2    | Desktop Type A   | SSD input C      | yes    | Cable #2 works      |     
 |    3    | Desktop Type C   | SSD input C      | yes    | Desktop Type C works|
```

The table shows that alone each of the three work (Desktop Type C, USB hub and Cable #2).
However, the combination does not. What could be the reason?

Comment: Let me get this straight, you're using a USB hub, and the devices work individually, but not all at the same time?  A hub doesn't really turn one port into four.  You are still limited by bandwidth of the USB bus and the individual port/cable.  You probably have too many devices sharing the same connection.

Comment: By work, I mean the LED comes on (also have tested it to actually work). But the hub works only when the other side is type A. (see above). The weird part is that the cable that does not work with the hub came with the hub.

Comment: If all devices work individually, then there's not a problem with the device and there's not a problem with your software (including OS and drivers).  It seems to me that this is a hardware limitation.  To which the only solution would be better hardware or a different hardware config

Comment: yes it seems that its a limitation on by desktop USB type C port or the Hub's controller, which does not allow the combination to work. Anyway its not critical. I was just bewildered with the behaviour and wanted to get to the bottom of it but does not seem to warrant that much time :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found your problem, it's the hub and cable not adhering to the USB spec.  Here's the evidence:

> (Type A male) <--> (Type A male)

And this:

> By work, I mean the LED comes on (also have tested it to actually work).

A cable that complies with the USB spec is not supposed to be able to have a male USB-A connector on both ends and still provide power.

Here's an example of a USB-A to USB-A cable that meets the spec: https://www.datapro.net/products/usb-3-0-super-speed-a-a-debugging-cable.html

In the description it points out that a compliant cable leaves the USB D+/D- and 5V pins unconnected.  Your USB-A to USB-C cable will connect the power pins on both connectors but it's "smart" enough not to supply power to a cable with a USB-A male end on it as the USB spec does not allow USB-A ports to take in power.

Do yourself a favor, and a favor to anyone around you, and destroy that cable and hub before someone uses that non-compliant cable in something other than that hub and starts a fire or something.

Replacing this hub with one that is new and complies with the spec would be something like $20.  Not replacing it runs the risk of far more damage than $20.  Take that cable and cut it in pieces so no one else picks it out of the trash to use.  Drop a brick on the hub too while you are at it.  Then go buy a new hub.